# Dependency Injection with ASP.Net MVC DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I'm using Unity.Mvc3 plugin for Dependency Injection with ASP.Net MVC application.
It is working fine with controllers with defined Services but not with Entity Framework DbContext objects.

**Scenario 1:** I have registered my Service and Interface as below in **Bootstrapper** and **Global.asax.cs** file:

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    container.RegisterType<IDashboardAppService, DashboardAppService>();
    ..........
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    .....
    Bootstrapper.Initialise();
}
```

And in Controller, I'm initializing the Service and calling the method. It is working fine.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private readonly IDashboardAppService _dashboardAppService;
        public HomeController(IDashboardAppService dashboardAppService)
        {
            _dashboardAppService = dashboardAppService;
        }
}
```

But If I want to use Both Service and DbContext class as bellow, I'm getting the error as

> "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe. Unity.MVC3"

Following is the error scenario :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDashboardAppService _dashboardAppService;
    private readonly RmgDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(IDashboardAppService dashboardAppService, RmgDbContext context)
    {
        _dashboardAppService = dashboardAppService;
        _context = context;
    }
 }
```

So how to handle both the scenarios?

Comment: Never worked with the techno, but have you double checked that you don't inject a  `RmgDbContext ` in its own ` OnModelCreating ` ? Not any of its child's `OnModelCreating ` if there is any ?

Comment: Where is the registration code for the DbContext with the container?

Comment: How to register DbContext with the container?

Comment: Something like container.RegisterType<DbContext, RmgDbContext >(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());  I'm not sure of the lifestyle selection for Unity, as I use Castle.Windsor.

Comment: I used `container.RegisterType<DbContext, RmgDbContext>( new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());` but same error